# Confused with F# List.Fold (powerset function)

Tags: f#, powerset

I understand and wrote a typical power set function in F# (similar to the *Algorithms* section in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set))

Later I found this implementation of powerset which seems nice and compact, expect that I do not understand it.

```
let rec powerset = function
                   | [] -> [[]]
                   | h::t -> List.fold (fun xs t -> (h::t)::t::xs) [] (powerset t);
```

I broke this down to a 1 step non-recursive function to find the powerset of [1;2] and hardcoded the value of power set of 2 at the end [[2]; []]

```
let right = function
                   | [] -> [[]]
                   | h::t -> List.fold (fun acc t -> (h::t)::t::acc) [] [[2]; []];
```

The output is `[[1]; []; [1; 2]; [2]]` which is correct.

However I was expecting List.Fold to output `[[1; 2]; []; [1; 2]; [2]]`.

Since I was not certain about the 't', I modified the variable names, and I did get what I had expected. Of course this is not the correct powerset of [1;2].

```
let wrong  = function
                  | [] -> [[]]
                  | h::t -> List.fold (fun acc data -> (h::t)::data::acc) [] [[2]; []];
```

For me 't' (the one withing fun and not the h::t) is simply a name for the second argument to 'fun' but that is obviously not the case. So what is the difference in the "right" and "wrong" F# functions I have written ? And what exactly does 't' here refer to ?

Thank you ! (I am new to F#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your "right" example, `t` is originally the name of the value bound in the pattern match, but it is hidden by the parameter `t` in the lambda expression passed to `List.fold`. Whereas in your "wrong" example, `t` is captured as a closure in the lambda expression. I think maybe you don't intend this capture, instead you want:

```
//now it works as you expect, replaced "t" with "data" in your lambda expression.
let wrong  = function
                  | [] -> [[]]
                  | h::t -> List.fold (fun acc data -> (h::data)::data::acc) [] [[2]; []];
```

Comment: Thank you ! That is exactly what I needed, and now the entire functions makes sense. The 't' arg made me look for patterns that did not exist :) !

Answer (score 1):

```
let rec powerset = function
                   | [] -> [[]]
                   | h::t -> List.fold (fun xs t -> (h::t)::t::xs) [] (powerset t);
```

here is the understanding/english translation of the code:

1. if the list (you want to power) is empty, then return a list, which contains an empty list in it
2. if the list is `h::t` (with head `h` and the rest as `t`, so `h` is an element and `t` is a list). then:

   A. `(powerset t)`: calculate the power set of `t`

   B. `(fun xs t -> (h::t)::t::xs)` means that you apply/fold this function to the `(powerset t)`. more details: `xs` is an accumulator, it is initialized to `[]`. `xxx::xs` means you add something to an existing powerest `xs`. Here `xxx` is `(h::t)::t`, which are two elements to be added to the head of `xs`. `(h::t)` means `add head to t` and `t` means each element in `(powerset t)`. <- the confusing part lies in `t`, the `t` in `(powerset t)` is the rest of the list, while the other `t` means an element in `(powerset t)`.

here is an imperative translation of the `fold` function :

```
let h::t = list
let setfort = powerset t
xs <- []
foreach s in setfort do
  xs <- xs.add(t) // t is a valid subset of list
  xs <- xs.add(h::t) // t with h is also a valid subset of list
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation of the function and especially the confusing part. It really had me confused ! :)

Answer (score -4):

`t` is a variable bound by pattern matching. List.fold is a fancy way of avoiding explicit looping. Now, go and read some introductory tutorials about F#.

Comment: I did read about List.Fold and t (the tail) but I do not understand what 't' signifies within a Fold. Is it that obvious ? I am sorry, but I just can't see it :-/